# Microsoft Project 2013, how to change Task ID to character instead of int

Tags: tasks, microsoft-project

Be default, in MS Project, task ID always are integer, can I change theme to UPPERCASE character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the simple answer is 'NO'. Task id is used by MSP to link tasks which is further used by the scheduling engine. Also resource leveling can be done based on Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom WBS code using letters and numbers. The Task IDs are set by Project and cannot be altered.